# Can I save the memoize cache?

Tags: node.js, memoization

I use memoize in a Node Web Service application.

1) When I shutdown the service, can I rescue the cache created before the shutdown?

2) The same scenario when I move my service to other server.

Can I save the cache in disk and then when the service begin assign to the memoize object again?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What memoization implementation are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I use medikko/memoize https://github.com/medikoo/memoize

Answer (score 0):

Memoize-fs is probably what you're looking for
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-fs